# Is the IPN response for Payments Standard the same as for Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

I am switching from Payments Standard to Express Checkout. Is the IPN response the same or different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one IPN parameter which is different `txn_type`
Check the IPN response for Website Payment Standard and express Checkout respectively.

For WPS : **txn_type=web_accept**

For EC  : **txn_type=express_checkout**

```
**IPN response for Payment Standard:** 
    cmd=_notify-validate
    mc_gross=10.01
    protection_eligibility=Eligible
    address_status=confirmed
    payer_id=ZK5AUW8MWY9CW
    tax=0.00
    address_street=3585+Petunia+Way%0D%0Aaddress+222
    payment_date=00%3A08%3A18+Apr+03%2C+2015+PDT
    payment_status=Completed
    charset=UTF-8
    address_zip=35045
    first_name=vimalbuyer
    mc_fee=0.59
    address_country_code=US
    address_name=azlan+xxxxx
    notify_version=3.8
    custom=
    payer_status=verified
    business=vimalnath53-facilitator%40gmail.com
    address_country=United+States
    address_city=Clanton
    quantity=1
    verify_sign=AEkJZp5PlgClTn1mxfylgc2FBYMzALsU7xcwTTHxpgXCri8asnzueXPK
    payer_email=vimalbuyer%40gmail.com
    contact_phone=408-329-3451
    txn_id=5GW24560KH817881A
    payment_type=instant
    last_name=ravichandran
    address_state=AL
    receiver_email=vimalnath53-facilitator%40gmail.com
    payment_fee=0.59
    shipping_discount=0.00
    insurance_amount=0.00
    receiver_id=S4X5XW328WAYY
    txn_type=web_accept
    item_name=Test+Item
    discount=0.00
    mc_currency=USD
    item_number=
    residence_country=US
    test_ipn=1
    shipping_method=Express
    handling_amount=0.00
    transaction_subject=
    payment_gross=10.01
    shipping=10.00
    ipn_track_id=97ef1f6957d55

**IPN response for Express Checkout:**
    cmd=_notify-validate
    mc_gross=0.01
    protection_eligibility=Eligible
    address_status=confirmed
    payer_id=ZK5AUW8MWY9CW
    tax=0.00
    address_street=3585+Petunia+Way%0D%0Aaddress+222
    payment_date=00%3A00%3A44+Apr+03%2C+2015+PDT
    payment_status=Completed
    charset=UTF-8
    address_zip=35045
    first_name=vimalbuyer
    mc_fee=0.01
    address_country_code=US
    address_name=azlan+xxxxx
    notify_version=3.8
    custom=
    payer_status=verified
    address_country=United+States
    address_city=Clanton
    quantity=1
    verify_sign=Au5ok3gYe0CeO2vF0KS59WJwgD0QAIljdpxKQfkvVQsbdbhT2o7SKMxQ
    payer_email=vimalbuyer%40gmail.com
    contact_phone=408-329-3451
    txn_id=207564537Y419840U
    payment_type=instant
    last_name=ravichandran
    address_state=AL
    receiver_email=vimalnath53-facilitator%40gmail.com
    payment_fee=0.01
    receiver_id=S4X5XW328WAYY
    txn_type=express_checkout
    item_name=
    mc_currency=USD
    item_number=
    residence_country=US
    test_ipn=1
    handling_amount=0.00
    transaction_subject=
    payment_gross=0.01
    shipping=0.00
    ipn_track_id=c50c795d8f17a
```

Also, look at the IPN variables that would be returned for each transaction [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)